# Setting cookie in c# webview control, then accessing that cookie from IE desktop app

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, cookies, webview

I basically just want to know if the webview control in C# and the desktop IE app are one and the same, can't find a suitable answer online:

If you set up an instance of a webview control in c#, and save a cookie from within that (i.e. by navigating it to a cookie creation page hosted by that domain, i.e. [https://somesite.com/createcookie.php?oneTimeTokenToInitiateCookie=34o7rcw37gxw37-etc-etc-etc"](https://somesite.com/createcookie.php?oneTimeTokenToInitiateCookie=34o7rcw37gxw37-etc-etc-etc%22)), would this cookie be accessible as normal if you then start IE from the desktop?  Or are the webview control and the desktop app completely separate instances of not necessarily the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

[WebView control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview) and IE browser are two different things. The doc says:

> This control uses the **Microsoft Edge rendering engine (EdgeHTML)** to embed a view that renders richly formatted HTML5 content from a remote web server, dynamically generated code, or content files.

WebView control uses EdgeHTML which is the Edge Legacy browser's rendering engine, so it has nothing related with IE.

As cookies are not shared between browsers, you can't access a cookie in IE which is set in a WebView control.